# Join table on itself subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to understand sub-queries better and i'm having a problem with this script below. (SQL Server database)

```
SELECT division_name, business_name, assignment_code, assignment_desc, last_name, first_name, total_salary, assign_fte, birth_year
  FROM table1 join
  (SELECT division_name, last_name, first_name, assignment_code, emp_id 
  FROM table1) raw
   WHERE raw.year_time = year_time
  AND division_name <> raw.division_name
  AND last_name = raw.last_name
  AND first_name = raw.first_name
    ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```

What I'm needing to do is join on the same table and extract data where an employee works for two different divisions.  The code above has a syntax error near the where clause.

Comment: You left off the ON clause. When you join a table you have to specify what to join on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the ON portion of your JOIN

i.e...

```
SELECT division_name, business_name, assignment_code, assignment_desc, last_name, first_name, total_salary, assign_fte, birth_year
  FROM table1 join
  (SELECT division_name, last_name, first_name, assignment_code, emp_id 
  FROM table1) raw ON raw.year_time = year_time
   WHERE
   division_name <> raw.division_name
  AND last_name = raw.last_name
  AND first_name = raw.first_name
    ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```